# Else can't find the If statement even though there is one

Tags: java, maze

When I try to compile this code I get an error saying else without if. I believe that I have all of the braces in the right place. I also get other errors to that are in the picture that I have attached but I just believe they are there because of the can't use else without if error.

Problem code:

```java
public static boolean goNorth(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[currCol]currRow - 1] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol][startRow -1] = PATH;
            currRow--;
            success = goNorth();
                if(!success){
                success = goWest();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goEast();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currRow++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }

    public static boolean goWest(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[currCol - 1]currRow] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol - 1][startRow] = PATH;
            currRow--;
            success = goWest();
                if(!success){
                success = goSouth();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goNorth();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currCol++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public static boolean goEast(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[currCol + 1]currRow] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol + 1][startRow] = PATH;
            currRow--;
            success = goEast();
                if(!success){
                success = goNorth();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goSouth();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currCol--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public static boolean goSouth(){
        boolean success;
        if(maze[currCol]currRow + 1] == CLEAR){
            maze[currCol][startRow + 1] = PATH;
            currRow--;
            success = goSouth();
                if(!success){
                success = goEast();
                    if(!success){
                    success = goWest();
                        if(!success){
                            maze[currCol][currRow] = VISITED;
                            currRow--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return success;
                } else {
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Error:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Post the text of the error, not a link to an image.

Comment: How about using any IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    if(maze[currCol + 1]currRow] == CLEAR){
```

That's not valid; you're missing the left bracket around `currRow` in a few places.

Also, there's a chunk of refactoring around this.

Comment: +1 for hawkeyeing it. This is what happens when your code is too bloated

Comment: Thank you. For your help. I should have caught this.

Answer (score 2):

Read the *first* error. Never read any error after the first error until you understand the first error.

The first error is telling you that you have a syntax error on this line:

```
if(maze[currCol]currRow - 1] == CLEAR){
```

(which you then copy-pasted four times). It's missing a `[` before `currRow`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help and I will be sure to do this in the future.